# Paste columns of two data frames

Tags: r, plyr

I find myself wanting to sometimes paste together columns from different dataframes (tables, matrices or whatever).  For example I have a table of means and a table of stan devs.  I want the two pasted together with the sd in a set of parentheses for latex printing.  I suspect there's a friendly plyr solution but can't think of how to work on two data frames ( I attempted storing the dataframes as a list and using ldply but this was my first attempt with a list plyr function and it went down in flames.

Thank you in advance.

```
#=========
#fake data
#=========
x<-mtcars[1:3,1:3]
y<-mtcars[1:3,8:10]


#==========================
#A column pasting function
#==========================
meansd<-function(x, y){
x<-round(x, dig=2)
y<-round(y, dig=2)
paste(x, "(", y, ")", sep="")
}
```

That's as far as I got.

**DESIRED OUTCOME**
No column names needed.  I don't care if the return is a matrix or dataframe.

```
16.46(0)  0(1)  1(4)
17.02(0)  0(1)  1(4)
18.61(1)  1(1)  1(4)
```

Comment: if you are looking to use this to produce regression summary tables in latex, then do take a look at `mtable` in the package `memisc`. it is a very flexible function that allows you to output your regression output in multiple formats with minimal effort.

Comment: @Ramnath  Thank you for your comment.  I became familiar with this package just recently.  It does a great deal of what I want for latex output but there's still a few things I need the flexibility to to some things mtable can't.

Comment: Are you going to `xtable` the resulting data.frame?

Comment: can you specify more clearly what is the output format you are looking at. `mtable` is super-flexible and it beats me that it can't do something standard :)

Comment: @gsk  Yes I'll use xtable with the solution (#3 solution [yours] is the one I like best; base package and simple), but I'll add some tweaks to it and make it one funtion that takes a means and sd table and produces a publishable means table..  Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your function edited to loop through and paste each column. This gives your desired result, but there is probably a cleverer way to do this.

```
meansd<-function(x, y){
    x<-round(x, digits = 2)
    y<-round(y, digits = 2)
    out <- matrix(ncol = dim(x)[1], nrow = dim(x)[2])
    for(i in 1:dim(x)[1])
    {
        out[i, ] <-paste(x[i, ], "(", y[i, ], ")", sep="")
    }
    return(out)
}
```

Comment: Ryan thank you for your response.  Works very well.  I'm hoping for a non loop answer if possible (I'm sure it is just don't know how).

Comment: This was the first answer that matched my specification and so I give it the accepted answer check.  I wished I could check each of the three.

Answer (score 10):

How about mapply?

```
x <- mtcars[1:3,1:3]
y <- mtcars[1:3,8:10]

mypaste <- function(x,y) paste(x, "(", y, ")", sep="")

mapply(mypaste, x,y)

     mpg       cyl    disp    
[1,] "21(0)"   "6(1)" "160(4)"
[2,] "21(0)"   "6(1)" "160(4)"
[3,] "22.8(1)" "4(1)" "108(4)"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I liked your `ldply` solution as well.  Similar flavor, just stirred with a little Hadley hammer.

Comment: My favorite solution.  Thank you.  Simple and beautiful.  Very creative thinking.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach using `plyr`

```
t(ldply(1:NCOL(x), function(i) meansd(x[,i], y[,i])))
```